# Failover plan for clearing active sessions?

Tags: php

I'm running a website which works with `$_SESSION` global variables.. I'm encountering a problem (when on the production/development zones) that the $_SESSION will clear its self when the user clears "active logins"

Is there a way to retain the contents of the session variables even after the user clears his/her active logins?

I'm currently considering a class to store a text document server-sided out of the public reach, which contains the users most recent session information. then when the user navigates, the PHP will try to detect if there is a text document available in the specified area, read the information and re-build the global variable...

This seems a little too in-depth of a solution, which i'm sure there might be other alternatives.. If there is. Could anyone point me in a place to look other than my solution listed above?

Comment: What do you mean by clear "active logins"? Do you mean when they clear their cookies?

Comment: @SimpleCoder Pretty much, take firefox for example.. when "clear recent history" it gives the options to: Cookies, Cache, Active logins for example.

Comment: Say you decide to implement your little text file solution. How do you identify which text file you're going to use?

Comment: @icktoofay It'll be referenced by the users `remote_addr` stored within the database. Pushed into the class, then the class will read a text document from the details pulled from the query

Comment: dont store anything you need to keep in a users session, put in a db associated with the user id

Comment: @Dagon But how would I go about referencing the user id from the database? with nothing to reference by?

Comment: @SophieMackeral: What if multiple users are behind one IP address? This happens when a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) is in place, which is more often than I think you believe.

Comment: If the user clears the cookies, let them be. Cookies where designed to keep track of such sessions. And what if that person is behind a dynamic IP? If it's given to someone else who doesn't have the cookies you set, will you consider them the same person who deleted their cookies or a different person? I say just let it be when someone deletes their cookies.

Comment: you need a proper log in system ip!=person

Comment: I just looked at [the relevant part of the Firefox source](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/d2a7cfa34154/browser/base/content/sanitize.js#l367) and clearing “Active Logins” should not remove any cookies, and thus, your `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @Dagon And if you build a custom session save handler that backends to the database you can still use $_SESSION superglobal :)

Comment: firefox's `active logins` are user/pass for http basic auth. it won't touch cookies. that's why there's a cookies option.